# sqlite database not opening in table view controller

Tags: ios, sql, database, xcode, sqlite

I'm making an app that essentially obtains data from the microphone and inputs it into an sqlite3 database.  I've been able to add the data to the database successfully, and the database updates with every entry, but for some reason when I try to display it in a table viewcontroller it says "database failed to open" (see code below).  So in the main viewcontroller the database updates fine, and obviously the database opens, but once I try to open the database in the table viewcontroller I get errors.

```
#import "TableViewController.h"

@interface TableViewController ()

@end

@implementation TableViewController
@synthesize entries;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    entries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self openDB];
    NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM PEFDATA"];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement = NULL;

    if(sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
            char *field1 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
            NSString *field1Str = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:field1];
            NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@", field1Str];
            [entries addObject:str ];
        }
    }

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//filePath to db
-(NSString *) filePath{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentationDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [[paths objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bp.sql"];
}

//open the db
-(void)openDB {
    if (sqlite3_open([[self filePath] UTF8String], & dbb) != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(dbb);
        //NSAssert(0,@"Database failed to open");
        NSLog(@"Database failed to open");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"database opened");
    }

}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *myTitle = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"Peak Flow History"];
    return myTitle;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [entries count];
    NSLog(@"%d",[entries count]);
}


-(IBAction)returned:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue{

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath       *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"test");
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier     forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.entries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

The real reason I want to be able to do this is so I can output the database (a single column) into an array so I can graph it, but I don't really need to see the data in table form.  In the online tutorial I watched, they outputted the database into an array so they could display the data in a tableviewcontroller.  But this seems like a round about way to do this.  So if anyone knows of a way to output a single column database into an array, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you checked the path you specified the database file is present or not ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the database file to the documents directory before you access it. Have you done that? Also you have not closed the database after opening it in viewdidload. You have to close the DB every time you open it.

```
-(void) copyDatabaseIfNeeded
{
    BOOL success;

    // Create a FileManager object, we will use this to check the status
    // of the database and to copy it over if required
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    // Check if the database has already been created in the users filesystem
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[self filePath]];

    // Get the path to the database in the application package
    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:strDatabaseName];

    // If the database already exists then return without doing anything
    if(success) 
    {
        return;
    }

    // If not then proceed to copy the database from the application to the users filesystem
    // Copy the database from the package to the users filesystem
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:[self filePath] error:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You car refer below code for converting a single column data to array here logininfo is a class which contains property and method related to database fields.

```
   -(NSArray *)getLoginDetail
{
    NSMutableArray *loginDetail = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    @try {

        NSArray *path_array = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *path_row = [path_array objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *final_phone_path = [path_row stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"loginDatabase.sqlite"];
        NSLog(@"%@",final_phone_path);


        NSFileManager *myFile_manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

        if (![myFile_manager fileExistsAtPath:final_phone_path])
        {
            NSLog(@"Fialed to find the database at path %@",final_phone_path);
            //return nil;
        }
        if (sqlite3_open([final_phone_path UTF8String], &dataBAse)!= SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"An error occured opening the data base...");
            //return nil;
        }
        //const char *sql_query = "SELECT id FROM page_data";
        const char *sql = "SELECT NAME,PASSWORD FROM loginData";

        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(dataBAse, sql, -1, &statement, nil) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error failed to prepare statement...%s",sqlite3_errmsg(dataBAse));
            //return nil;
        }
        while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            //int uniqueID=sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
            const char *nameChar =  (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement,0);
            const char *passwordChar = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
            NSLog(@"value from DB is : %@",[NSString stringWithUTF8String:nameChar]);
            NSLog(@"value from DB is : %@",[NSString stringWithUTF8String:passwordChar]);



            NSString *name1=[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:nameChar];
            NSString *password1=[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:passwordChar];
           // NSlog("%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:name1]);
            loginInfo *info=[[loginInfo alloc]initWithName:name1 password:password1];
            [loginDetail addObject:info];

            //if(textFieldName.text==demo1 && textFieldPassword.text == demo2){
            //[self buttonClicked];
            //break;

        }
        if (sqlite3_finalize(statement) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"Failed to finalize data statement, normally error handling here.");
        }
        if (sqlite3_close(dataBAse) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"Failed to close database, normally error handling here.");
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"An exception occurred: %@", [exception reason]);
        //return nil;
    }
    @finally {

    }
    return loginDetail;
}
```